# How to add font awesome to rails 7 (jsbundling)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

Sorry this topic has been covered many times.  However, I just created a new rails 7 app using esbuild, added font-awesome-sass to the gem file, created application.css.scss (already had application.bootstrap.scss) and put "@import 'font-awesome';" in there.

I then added the following to a view page:

```
      <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-house"></i>
      <%= icon 'fa-brands', 'font-awesome' %>
```

No page errors, no console errors---but, the icons are not visible on the page (code is in the source).  I've been mindlessly trying to figure this out---but, can not figure out why this is not working.

Have I missed any step?

I've verified installation instructions for the gem, I also tried skipping the gem and installing fontawesome via yarn.  Nothing has gotten icons to show up in the view.

Answer (score 6):

As are you using esbuild, you can install fontawesome with npm or yarn

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and import it in your javascript/application.js

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
```

Just remember to use only the free icons, **fa-sharp** is not free

Comment: I am using esbuild, but I chose the gem for access to their helper methods.

Comment: I'm using esbuild and this answer helped me resolve the issue

Comment: Using your solution, is there a way to import only icons needed into the application?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use CSS-based fontawesome rather than JS, you can do the following similar to the answer from [Bouaik Lhoussaine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74360023/278842):

Install via Yarn:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Import it in your javascript/application.js. This enables [CSS in JS bundling for esbuild (documented here)](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#css-from-js) and will let esbuild generate an `application.css` next to the `application.js`.

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all" // Notice: css not js
```

Then you need to adjust the build config in `package.json` so that `esbuild` knows which loaders to provide for tff and woff2 by adding `--loader:.ttf=file --loader:.woff2=file`:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets --loader:.ttf=file --loader:.woff2=file",
    ...
```

Next, you need to ensure that your `css-bundling` solution doesn't also create an `application.css` file which would conflict with the one created by `esbuild`. For `tailwind` for instance, I adjusted the name of the output like this so that it generates `application.tailwind.css` rather than `application.css`:

```
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.tailwind.css --minify"
  }
```

Last, you need to add a stylesheet tag in your `application.html.erb` so that the new `application.tailwind.css` is loaded:

```
// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.tailwind", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we are using Rails 7, we don't like sass due to annoying installation, here I figured out how to get fontawesome works with **tailwindcss + propshaft**

**install package**

```bash
# install package
$ yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

**import fontawesome css**

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "./base.css";

/* import fontaweseome css */
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all";

@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "./components.css";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**copy fonts to vendor folder**

```bash
# copy fonts
$ mkdir -p vendor/assets/fonts/fontawesome
$ cp -r node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/ vendor/assets/fonts/fontawesome
```

**install postcss-replace plugin**

```bash
# install postcss-replace to replace fontawesome static font path from css
$ yarn add -D postcss-replace
$ touch postcss.config.js
```

**use postcss-replace to replace fonts path**

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    // replace url("../webfonts/ to url("./fontawesome/
    'postcss-replace': {
      pattern: /url\("\.\.\/webfonts\//,
      data: { replaceAll: 'url("./fontawesome/' }
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

**build tailwindcss with postcss**

```js
"build:css": "tailwindcss --postcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried with [this](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/ruby-on-rails) and everything is fine, Could you try it?

### Updated Steps:

1. create project with cmd `rails _7.0.4_ new demo-rails-with-react-frontend -j esbuild`
2. add font awesome following [this](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/ruby-on-rails)
3. create component to test following [this](https://blog.dennisokeeffe.com/blog/2022-02-19-rails-7-using-react-with-esbuild)

---

The result (image below)
[image]

my file `app/javascript/components/application.tsx`:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface AppProps {
  arg: string;
}

const App = ({ arg }: AppProps) => {
  return <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>;
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const rootEl = document.getElementById("root");
  ReactDOM.render(<App arg="Rails 7 with ESBuild" />, rootEl);
});
```

#### ENV

- ruby 3.0.4
- rails 7.0.4
- font-awesome-sass 6.2.0

Comment: That is exactly what I followed.  I chose the gem over yarn so I can utilize the gem helpers.  But, the icons don't show in the view.

Comment: i updated the steps that i did.